# How to traverse an graph branch, from specific node with Boost.Graph?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

Will be grateful for help .
I have tree structure and want print nodes in order of occurrence, with respect of hierarchy .

For example I wan traverse all child of N1:

```
[N0, N1[N2, N3, N4[N5], N6]
```

And I'm expect to get

```
N1 N2 N3 N4 N5
```

But I'm receive something different, using this snippet :

```
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> MyGraph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor MyVertex;

        class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
        {
        public:
          void discover_vertex(MyVertex v, const MyGraph& g) const
          {
            cerr << v << endl;
            return;
          }
        };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
     MyGraph g;

        boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
        boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
        boost::add_edge(0, 3, g);
        boost::add_edge(2, 4, g);

        MyVisitor vis;

        //2 - N2 node 
        boost::depth_first_search(g,  boost::visitor(vis).root_vertex(2) );
        return 0;

}
```

Output is :

```
2
0
1
3
4
```

but I'm expect (2 and all childs)

```
2
4
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You receive, what, exactly? Because that "snippet" doesn't do anything, really

Comment: sehe - sorry. Fixed! Full snippet added with output samples .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graph is undirected, which means that the backedge (0,2) is also taken.

Try changing `undirectedS` to `directedS`

To avoid reporting vertices discovered from additional roots, you could adjust the visitor to detect when the first `root` is `done`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a689c963c3aa01f9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <iterator>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>;
using VertexPair = std::pair<Graph::vertex_descriptor, Graph::vertex_descriptor>;

struct Visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    using V = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    void discover_vertex(V v, const Graph& /*g*/) {
        if (!root) {
            root = v;
        }
        if (!done) std::cerr << v << "\n";
    }

    void finish_vertex(V v, const Graph& /*g*/) {
        done |= (root == v);
    }
  private:
    bool done = false;
    boost::optional<V> root;
};

int main() {
    // [N0, N1[N2, N3, N4[N5], N6] :
    // VertexPair const data[] { {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {4, 5}, };
    VertexPair const data[] { {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 4}, };
    Graph g(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 7);

    boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(Visitor()).root_vertex(2));
    //boost::write_graphviz(std::cout, g);
}
```

Prints

```
2
4
```

**UPDATE**

If for efficiency you want to avoid traversing the remainder of the tree, you can use `depht_first_visit` which can take a `TerminatorFunc`. Here I added that to the same visitor:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8908c6e61815b1e4)</kbd>**

```
// in Visitor:

    // the TerminatorFunc
    bool operator()(V, Graph const&) const { return done; }

// later:

    Visitor vis_termfuc; // combines visitor and terminator functions
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colormap(num_vertices(g));
    boost::depth_first_visit(g, 2, vis_termfuc, colormap.data(), vis_termfuc);
```

Comment: Sehe, thank you for  hint. Now result is much better .

2
4
0
1
3

Only I need is cut-off all nodes after 4.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to stop it from the visitor then. Lemme see

Comment: @user1503944 Added a slightly more efficient approach that stops the search earlier [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8908c6e61815b1e4)

Comment: Sehe,it's look like it works  for me ! Thanks a lot ! Because my MSVC compiler  not  C++11 ready, some modification was added .